# Function is to relation as functor is to?

Tags: category-theory

I am told that the answer to the question in the title is a [profunctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profunctor). However, below I sketch a different way that one could think about structure-preserving relations between categories. My questions are

1. Is the thing I define below the same thing as a profunctor (for small categories at least)? If so, how can I see the connection?
2. If not, does the thing I define have a name, and can it be satisfactorily defined in general, not just for small categories? And is it useful for anything?

Here's my definition:

> Let $C$ and $D$ be small categories. Define a relator (for want of a better name) as a relation $\sim$ between ${\rm Ob}(C)$ and ${\rm Ob}(D)$ and a relation that I'll also denote $\sim$ between the morphisms of $C$ and the morphisms of $D,$ such that:
>
> - For $P\in {\rm Ob}(C)$ and $X\in {\rm Ob}(D)$, if $P\sim X$ then ${\rm Id}_P \sim {\rm Id}_X$
> - For morphisms $f:P\to Q$ in $C$ and $u:X\to Y$ in $D$, if $f\sim u$ then $P\sim X$ and $Q\sim Y$.
> - For morphisms $f:P\to Q$ and $g:Q\to R$ in $C$, and $u:X\to Y$ and $v:Y\to Z$ in $D$, if $f\sim u$ and $g\sim v$, then $f;g \sim u;v$.

The point being that a functor is just a special case of this, in which every object in $C$ relates to exactly one object in $D$, and every morphism in $C$ relates to exactly one morphism in $D.$

I restricted it to small categories because a relation is a subset of the Cartesian product, which isn't defined for proper classes. I do not have a good idea about how it would generalise.

Comment: Check this out too: https://zellerede.ml/profunctors

Comment: @Berci that looks great, thank you! I had been wondering for myself if they could be characterised like this: "A profunctor ... connects up two categories by (potentially) adding more morphisms in between them ‘from the outer world’. In other perspective, we can describe this setting as one of the two categories acting from the left and the other one acting from the right on the newly added morphisms." I will read through that in detail later.

Comment: Or stated more clearly on the same page: "A category $F$ is called a profunctor between $A$ and $B$, if it disjointly and fully contains $A$ and $B$ and any other arrow of $F$ goes from an object of $A$ to an object of $B$." It's too bad he doesn't give a proof that this is equivalent to the standard definition.

Comment: It seems clear though that the sets in the conventional definition are the hom-sets (or rather het-sets) between objects of A and objects of B.

Comment: Yes, that's the correspondence. The original version can be obtained by the restriction of the hom-functor $\mathcal F^{op}\times\mathcal F\to Set$ to $\mathcal C^{op}\times\mathcal D$. In the other direction, the compositions (left and right actions) can be defined using the morphism part of the functor $\mathcal C^{op} \times\mathcal D\to Set$.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition makes perfect sense, and in essence it's nothing else but a *subcategory of $C\times D$*.

Note, however, the composition of two such relations *does not necessarily* satisfy the given properties, as we can have $\alpha:a\to b$ and $\beta:c\to d$ in $C$ with different objects $a,b,c,d$, and $a\sim x,\ b\sim y,\ c\sim y,\ d\sim z,\ \alpha\sim\xi,\ \beta\sim\eta$ with $\xi:x\to y,\ \eta:y\to z$ in $D$, then in the composition $\sim^{op};\sim$ we should have $\xi;\eta$ with itself, which is not guaranteed.

However, every such relation indeed gives rise to a profunctor (actually, one in both directions), by formally adding an arrow $c\to d$ [resp. $d\to c$] to the disjoint union of $C$ and $D$, whenever $c\sim d$, and define formal compositions with these, such that whenever $\alpha\sim\gamma$, the corresponding square is made commutative.

Comment: Indeed, there is no associative composition of binary relations in $\mathbf{Cat}$ because $\mathbf{Cat}$ is not a regular category.

Comment: @Berci After your answer, I got back to my attempt to build a profunctor out of the axioms proposed. I thaught I could finally build the profunctor, but there seems to be lacking something in the axioms proposed if we want to build the profunctor : if $c_1 \sim d_1$ and we have a morphism $f: c_2\to c_1$, then $c_2 \sim d_1$ and if $g:d_1 \to d_2$, $c_1 \sim d_2$. (composition of the formally added arrow with the already existing ones).

Comment: Why would we have $c_2\sim d_1$? You can work with the formal compositions so that a heteromorphism can be written rigorously as $\langle f, u_{cd}, g\rangle$ where $u_{cd}:c\to d$ is the freely adjoint arrow for $c\sim d$ and $f:c'\to c,\ g:d\to d'$.

Comment: Yes I see now ! my problem was I wanted the image of $(c,d)$ to be the singleton if $c\sim d$, and empty otherwise, so there was only one morphism between pairs $(c,d)$ and that forced the axioms of compositions I wrote in my previous comments. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my response is more like an extended comment than a real answer but the comments section is to small.

A relation between the sets $C$ and $D$ is a function $C \times D \to \{0,1\}$.

A function $f$ between the sets $C$ and $D$ is then a relation if you consider the following function
$$
(c,d)\mapsto \chi_{\{d = f(c)\}} = \left\{ \array{1 \text{ if }d=f(c) \\ 0 \text{ otherwise}}\right.
$$

A profunctor between $C$ and $D$ is a functor $D^{op}\times C \to \text{Set}$.

A functor $F$ between $C$ and $D$ is then a profunctor if you consider the following 
$$
(d,c) \mapsto \text{Hom}_D(d,F(c)).
$$
You can see $\text{Hom}$ as a categorified characteristic function, it may be empty (corresponding to 0) if $d$ and $F(c)$ are not related, or it is non empty (corresponding to 1) if they are.

A functor $F:C\to D$ is a relator if seen in the following way :

- $c\sim d $ iff $F(c) = d$
- $u \sim f$ iff $F(u) = f$

**The following discussion is wrong**

> Your device doesn't seem to produce a functor $D^{op}\times C \to \text{Set}$. Say you have a relator $R$ from $C$ to $D$, if $(d,c)$ is an object of $D^{op}\times C$, then I imagine you want to send it to the singleton if $c \sim_R d$ or the empty set otherwise. If we have a morphism $(u,v)$ between $(d_1,c_1)$ to $(d_2,c_2)$ where $u : d_2 \to d_1$ and $v : c_1 \to c_2$ here you get a problem of covariance, and even if you flip things around in your definition for $D$, then it may be the case that $d_1 \nsim_R c_2$ and $d_2 \sim_R c_1$, and you will have trouble defining a map from $\{*\} \to \emptyset$. I cannot see how to use the data of the relation on arrows to help with this issue.

**Edit after Berci's answer, and a discussion in the comments**

Don't know why I couldn't build a profunctor out of the given data but, following [the link proposed by Berci](https://zellerede.ml/wordpress/2018/01/05/plenty-faces-of-a-profunctor/), define $\chi : C^{op}\times D \to \text{Set}$, by

$$(c,d)\mapsto \coprod_{x\sim y} \text{Hom}_C(c,x)\times \text{Hom}_D(y,d)$$

Of course there is a symmetric profunctor $\xi : D^{op}\times C \to Set$, given by,
 $$(d,c)\mapsto \coprod_{x\sim y} \text{Hom}_D(d,y)\times \text{Hom}_C(x,c),$$
as anounced by Berci.

Comment: +1, this is helpful. I don't think I was trying to produce a categorification of the notion of relation (I'm not sure I have a good grasp of what that would entail). It's just a nagging thought I keep having while learning the basics of category theory. I think of a function as just a special case of a relation, and (for small categories) a functor is just a function with some extra restrictions. So it seems like a functor should really just be a special case of a relation with certain restrictions, and if I could understand that it might help me understand how it fits together a bit better.

Comment: In some sense a functor is a special case of a profunctor, but  since profunctors are defined in terms of functors, and seem in general more complicated and less elemental than them, they don't currently seem to be helping my intuition very much. (This may of course change as I learn more category theory in general.)

Comment: :) that is why I stressed out that we can see a relation on sets as a function (with values in the $\{0,1\}$), and if you want, the profunctor $\text{Hom}_C$ is the analougous to the equality relation on $C$.

Comment: maybe I can add this in the answer : a relation will produce a function on the sets of subsets of the sets involved, a profunctor will produce a functor on the categories of presheaves of the categories involved.

Comment: Idle wondering: a relation can be defined in an equivalent way that doesn't depend on the definition of a function, as a subset of the Cartesian product. That makes it easier to see that a function is a special case of a relation, because we don't have to worry about a relation being defined as a special case of a function. I wonder if a similarly elementary definition can be given of a profunctor, without relying on the definition of a functor. Then it would be much easier to see functors as the special case. (This is probably straightfoward and I intend to work through it when I have time.)